# Naming for image sequence?

Tags: compositing-nodes, video-sequence-editor, image

I am working in compositor and VSE and find that Blender does not seem to understand image-sequences named like 120311_115058__001.jpg?
What are the rules for naming img-sequences?
*Thanks*

Answer (score 1):

There should be no issue with such naming. As long as the end of the file name is that of the sequence, for exqample: xxxx_xxx_#### in which # stands for the frame number.

If you are importing into the VSE make sure you select all of the frames that are part of the sequence (press <kbd>A</kbd>).

[image]

As for the compositor use an **Image Sequence** node you just need to select the first image in the sequence. Then enable Match movie length and Auto_Refresh.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but still not working. Filename starting with 100105_115616_0001.jpg, and when I open the first one in the compositor the node is set to image sequence. But "Frames" is set to 1 and if I increase it, the thumbnail disappears.. "Match movie length" does not seem to do anything.

Comment: Also have a cyclic button..? Using 77a

Comment: Renamed the files to 0001.jpg and now work as expected.